# Java: Display text at top

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, caret

I have a simple display routine

```
    public static void showEngineAnalysis(String message) {

    if (message.length() > 0)
        message += "\n";
    Application.obj.engineOutput.append(message);

}
```

which prints data from an input stream below

```
      public void getEngineOutputOriginal(Process engine) 
  {
        try {

                  BufferedReader reader =
                  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(engine.getInputStream()), 1);
                  String lineRead = null;
                  while((lineRead = reader.readLine()) != null) 

                  Application.showEngineAnalysis(lineRead);//send engine analysis to print method

             }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }
  }
```

I would like the display routine to print the next line at the top of my JTextArea (engineOutput) instead at the bottom, i.e. from:

1. e7e6 b1c3 2. c5d4 e3d4
2. e7e6 c4d5 2. e6d5
3. c5d4 e3d4 2. b8c6

to

1. c5d4 e3d4 2. b8c6
2. e7e6 c4d5 2. e6d5
3. e7e6 b1c3 2. c5d4 e3d4

I totally can't figure it out (I tried caret positions, etc)

Answer (score 2):

You could insert the text instead of appending it.

```
public static void showEngineAnalysis(String message) {
    if (message.length() > 0)
        message += "\n";
    Application.obj.engineOutput.insert(message, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Roger.  That worked a treat first time round.  Delighted :-)

Comment: +1 I'd be use getDocumnet.insertString, sure in this case doesn't matter

Comment: @mKorbel JTextAreas does a localDocument.insertString internally for insert so they should be equivalent.